# replace hotlinked image with html code

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I found out a competitor of mine copied my webpage and in the process hotlinked an image on his page - he probably just copy/pasted from the browser.
I know how to handle hotlinking, but I want to attempt a better version of it: I want to replace the http://www.mysite.invalid/image.jpg on his page with html code using htaccess so when his page with the html

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.invalid/image.jpg" />
```

would be replaced by

```
dontstealbandwidth.jpg"/> this image steals bandwidth from <a href="http://mysite.invalid">mysite.invalid</a><img src="dontstealbandwidth.jpg
```

The result in his page would then be

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.invalid/dontstealbandwidth.jpg"/> this image steals bandwidth from <a href="http://mysite.invalid">mysite.invalid</a><img src="dontstealbandwidth.jpg" />
```

I tried to redirect the image to an html file. Directly accessing the image on my site will show the content of the html file. However this does not seem to work on images inside html code. 
Is this at all possible? It feels like it shouldn't be but it would be cool if it would be.
Is it at all possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When a browser is requesting image data then you cannot return HTML text in response. You can of course **make a custom image** named `/dontstealbandwidth.jpg` with your HTML text embedded in it and redirect `/image.jpg` to `/dontstealbandwidth.jpg` using simple redirect rule like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/image\.jpg$ /dontstealbandwidth.jpg
```

Comment: hi, I understand this much, but I wanted to embed a hyperlink to my site in the code. This is not possible with an image afaik